# How to get all URLs redirect to HTTPS in Nginx , except this one

Tags: ssl, redirect, nginx

I have already this 301 redirect working, but I need to leave one url pattern out, so it is served by http. Right now I use this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I tried this before the return:

```
 location /wp-json {
   return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

But it didn't help. I need any URL starting with http://www.example.com/wp-json/* to not be redirected through HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # Redirect to HTTPS, unless it begins with /wp-json/
    if ($uri !~* "^/wp-json/") {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But it just don't redirect when it finishes with /wp-json 
When it has something after "/wp-json", which is always the case, it still redirects.